# How to recover OSX clipboard history, assuming I don't have a third-party clipboard app already installed?

Tags: macos, copy-paste, clipboard

Using the `⌘X` shortcut on my Mac, I cut a piece of text (call it *A*) with the intention of pasting it, but before doing so I inadvertently copied another piece of text (call it *B*). I'm now trying to recover *A*. Is it lost forever?

I do not currently have any third-party apps for this purpose; an app would only help if it can recover clipboard content dating to before the app's installation.

I'm using Mac OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks)

Comment: It's ephemeral; consider it gone.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there isn't any history built into OS X.  I would use something like [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/) that does that, text expansion and many other things.